# Dom parser in android ics, can not get elements by tag name

Tags: android

I try to use dom parser get value from a xml file like:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                xml_string.getBytes());
        Document pdom = pbuilder.parse(inputStream);
        Element proot = pdom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList pitems = proot.getElementsByTagName("Profile");
```

But the pitems size is 0, actually, The code above is working in version before 4.0.
So i hope i can get the the name and ismember item.
Don't know how to get it now.
Pls help me.

the xml formate:

```
<Profile parameter="S...J">
   <Name>Jon</Name>
   <IsMember>true</Ismember>
</Profile>
```

Comment: Hi. i post the xml file ready. Pls help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your XML like this

```
<root>
<Profile parameter="SJ">
   <Name>Jon</Name>
   <IsMember>true</IsMember>
</Profile>
</root>
```

and then all other things will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:

```
Document pdom = pbuilder.parse(inputStream);
Element proot = pdom.getDocumentElement();
proot.normalize();  //must call

NodeList pitems = document.getElementsByTagName("Profile");  //get element from document
```